# Change date format for array to MySQL format using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

My array date `format ($fanniemaeDate)` that I am passing to the database table `column (date)` is 11/19/2013 and I am trying to convert it to the MySQL format 2013-11-19 in my PDO prepare statement, however it is giving me an error `"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"`

I'm just learning PDO so not sure what is wrong with my `STR_TO_DATE` format within the prepare statement, or if this is even the correct way to prepare the statement.

If I remove the `STR_TO_DATE` from the prepare statement it will pass the time and rate correctly with the date stored as `0000-00-00`

I need to know the correct way to write the prepare statement.

```
//PDO insert prepare statement for fannie_90dayrate table
$insertIrate = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO fannie_90dayrate (date, time, 90dayrate) 
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(':fanniemaeDate', '%m/%d/%Y'), :fanniemaeTime, :fanniemaeRate)");  

//PDO execute statement
$insertIrate->execute(array(
':fanniemaeDate' => $fanniemaeDate['Fannie Mae Date'],
':fanniemaeTime' => $fanniemaeTime['Fannie Mae Time'],
':fanniemaeRate' => $fanniemaeRate['Fannie Mae Rate']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `:fanniemaeDate` in

```
... STR_TO_DATE(':fanniemaeDate', '%m/%d/%Y') ...
```

Placing quotes around a parameter placeholder will cause it to be ignored, thus unbalancing your number of placeholders / number of parameters.

#### Side note...

I would recommend working with actual `DateTime` objects in PHP instead of date strings. That way, you can switch formats around quite easily, for example

```
$fanniemaeDate['Fannie Mae Date'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '11/19/2013');

// snip

$insertIrate->execute(array(
    ':fanniemaeDate' => $fanniemaeDate['Fannie Mae Date']->format('Y-m-d'),
    // etc
```

This way, you avoid having to convert the date string in the query.